# PostgreSQL - grouping error with Case and When to avoid division by zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

> ERROR: column "sams_ar_pb_rebuild.plan_units_ty" must appear in the
> GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

```
select
    channel,
    category,
    club,
    week_ending,
    sum(eligible_units_ty) as "Eligible Units",
    sum(eligible_revenue_ty)::numeric as "Eligible Revenue",
    sum(plan_units_ty) as "Plan Units",
    sum(plan_revenue_ty)::numeric::money as "Plan Revnue",
   case when plan_units_ty =0 then null
   else round(100*(sum(plan_units_ty)/sum(eligible_units_ty)),1)end as "AR"
from operations.sams_ar_pb_rebuild 
    where week_ending >= '2023-01-01'and category not in ('Mattresses','Monthly Mobile')
 group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc, 4 desc
```

WHen not using case then it will resulted in division by zero error code

Comment: Use nullif() to replace a 0 with a null. If you need some other default value, you can then use coalesce() to replace the null with something

Comment: The error message '_"column "sams_ar_pb_rebuild.plan_units_ty" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function_' is very helpful.

Comment: Try `group by 1,2,3,4,9`

Comment: What do you want to happen when `sum(eligible_units_ty)` is 0?

Comment: I tried group by 1,2,3,4,9 and it didnt work

Comment: Sum(eligible_units) will never be 0

Comment: @JVEZ Unless you have a `check eligible_units_ty > 0` the sum can be zero. There's nothing else you're dividing by to cause the error. Can we see the complete error, please?

Answer (score 1):

Every non-aggregate column must appear in the group by clause. Originally the column was presumably just the sums, but `case when plan_units_ty =0 then null` is not aggregated. And it won't solve your problem.

Looking at `sum(plan_units_ty)/sum(eligible_units_ty)`, the divide-by-zero error is when `sum(eligible_units_ty)` is 0. You need to account for that.

```
   case when sum(eligible_units_ty) = 0 then 'NaN'
   else round(100*(sum(plan_units_ty)/sum(eligible_units_ty)),1)end as "AR"
```

All branches of the case must return the same type, so it has to be a number. I chose `NaN` (Not A Number).

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/EPTVGvHl).

Answer (score 0):

try using nullif the value is 0

```
round(100*(sum(plan_units_ty)/Nullif(sum(eligible_units_ty),0)),1)end as "AR"
```